# Laravel version - 4.2 logout is not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, logout

`NotFoundHttpException` showing when load the page when i am logout it is showing 404 error  it is showing object not found showing the rout section is given below:

```
route.php
Route::get('logout',array('uses' => 'LoginController@logout'));
```

the controller is LoginController

```
    public function logout()
    {
        //Session::flush();
         Auth::logout(); 
         return Redirect::to('login');
    }
```

and anchor tag is

```
<li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
```

but it is showing

```
Object not found! 404 error
```

Comment: logout method needs permission 'auth' in routes

Comment: where i need to use auth

Answer (score 0):

`Route::group(['namespace' => 'YourNameSpace', 'before' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('logout', [
        'uses' => 'LoginController@logout',
    ]);
});`

'auth'  must be defined in filters